# OpenERP 7 Login flow

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I need to know how is the flow in OpenERP for Login process.
which function call at begin.?
I debug using eclipse and seems start with **main.py** (`def login_and_redirect` ) then goes to **res_users.py** (`def login`,`def authenticate`)

is this correct.?which is the trigger point to call login function.
i checked in **base.xml** also.but unable to find place which is called to a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard authentication (without using auth_x modules) in openerp follows a complex process.

The login form is defined in openerp/addons/web/static/src/xml/base.xml.

When cliking on Login button, the following functions are called in this order:

```
on_submit() then do_login() then session_authenticate() in openerp/addons/web/static/src/js/chrome.js

session_authenticate() in openerp/addons/web/static/src/js/coresetup.js

authenticate() in openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py

authenticate() in openerp/addons/web/session.py

exp_authenticate() in openerp/service/web_services.py

authenticate in openerp/addons/base/res/res_users.py
```